# PHP - creating a PNG file with semi-transparent logo / watermark

Tags: php, gd

I'm trying to place a logo into a white image and make it semi-transparent to be used as a watermark.

Here is my code...

```
   // load the stamp and the photo to apply the watermark to
   if (file_exists($logoPath)) {

      $im = imagecreatefrompng($logoPath);
      $size = getimagesize($logoPath);

      $stamp = imagecreatetruecolor(612, 792);
      imagefilledrectangle($stamp, 0, 0, 612-1, 792-1, 0xFFFFFF);
      $sx = imagesx($stamp);
      $sy = imagesy($stamp);

      // center width and height
      $centerX=$sx/2-$size[0]/2;
      $centerY=$sy/2-$size[1]/2;

      $res=imagecopymerge($stamp, $im, $centerX,$centerY, 0, 0, $sx, $sy, 15);

      $waterPath = $watermark_path.$broker_id."_watermark.png";

      // Save the image to file and free memory
      imagepng($stamp, $waterPath);
      imagedestroy($stamp);
      imagedestroy($im);
   }
```

It all looks good to me but when I run it I get this...

http://i43.tinypic.com/2cyft06.jpg

...as you can see, the lower right quad of the image is getting colored for some reason.

Comment: I think you need to do something with alpha.

Comment: yeah..maybe..but the logo *is* being made transparent correctly with the imagecopymerge...it's just coloring everything on the $stamp that comes "after" the image...very odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you take a look at [`imagecopymerge()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) docs, the 7th and 8th arguments represent the source image width and height amount. You appear to pass the target image height (612, 792), so basically you're trying to copy a 612x792 slice from your logo image, which looks much smaller.

I'll try to better describe the arguments:

```
$res = imagecopymerge(
          $stamp,           // <- target image
          $im,              // <- source image, from where to copy (logo)
          $centerX,         // <- target x-position (where to place your logo), 
          $centerY,         // <- target y-position 
          0,                // <- source x-position (x-offset from where to start copy)
          0,                // <- source y-position
          imagesx($im),     // <- amount to copy from source (width)
          imagesy($im),     // <- amount... (height)
          15                // <- i have no idea what this is :)
        );
```

Comment: ...and also...the 15 at the end is the transparency blend ratio...0 is totally transparent 100 is no transparent :)